# How to find Invariant equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, proof-explanation

How did they get the invariant equation?  And what is the process for finding such equations?

$\phantom{}$
[image]

- **Solution**

[image]

Comment: I added an edit that explains my thought process a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (credit @johnfowles): Suppose we began by looking for an invariant equation. Then taking the equation mod 10 doesn't change the invariant from being a constant, if it was invariant without it. So that step seems to be a step that doesn't change the invariant constant, but it allows us to equate coefficients on corresponding $x_i$'s.

For more information on @johnfowles methodology to understand the *why* of this, please look at the comments.

Since the seventh term is the sum mod 10, the invariant is a constant expressed by some operations of a set of six consecutive terms. Also, since the seventh is the **sum**, I would hazard that the invariant is a weighted sum, as in each term is multiplied by a different coefficient. Since the last term is taken mod 10, the entire invariant is also taken mod 10.

Let's take the first two sequences:

\begin{align}
&x_1, &x_2, &x_3, &x_4, &x_5, &x_6\\
&x_2, &x_3, &x_4, &x_5, &x_6, &(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6)\mod{10}\\
&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f\\
\end{align}
(forgive the formatting, idk why align isn't working)

Take $a, b, ... f$ to be the coefficients of the invariant.

Now consider each $x$ separately in the total sum.

\begin{align}
a\cdot x_1 &\equiv f \cdot x_1 \mod 10\\
b \cdot x_2 &\equiv (a+f) \cdot x_2\mod 10 \text{ (i'll ignore the variables now)}\\
c &\equiv b+ f \mod 10\\
d &\equiv c+ f \mod 10\\
e &\equiv d+ f \mod 10\\
f &\equiv e+ f \mod 10\\
\end{align}
Now substitute $a \equiv f$
\begin{align}
a&\equiv f \mod 10\\
b &\equiv 2f \mod 10 \\
c &\equiv 3f \mod 10\\
d &\equiv 4f \mod 10\\
e &\equiv 5f \mod 10\\
f &\equiv 6f \mod 10\\
\end{align}
Clearly, $a \equiv f \equiv 2, b \equiv 4, c \equiv 6, d \equiv 8, e\equiv 10$.

Note that $f=12 \equiv 2 \mod 10$

Comment: Could you explain to me how you got the equations $a\cdot x_1 \equiv f\cdot x_1$ mod $10$,  $b\cdot x_2 \equiv (a+f)\cdot x_2$ mod $10$,....  Since distributivity doesn't apply to sums mod some number I don't see how you isolated $f\cdot x_1$ mod $10$, from the $f(x_1+...x_6)$ mod $10$.  And are you adding the $2$ sequences or equating them?

Comment: Well, we know that there is some invariant. Since $x_1, x_2...$ are independent, we can consider them separately. There must be the same number of $x_1$'s in the first set of six and the second set of six. There must also be the same number of $x_2$'s in the first set of six and the second set of six. This can then be extended to all the $x_n$

Comment: So because the invariant is mod $10$, we can write  $\bigg(ax_2+...+ex_6 + f(x_1+...+x_6)$mod $10 \bigg)$ mod $10 =\big(ax_2+...+ex_6 + fx_1$mod $10 +...+fx_6$mod $10 \big)$ mod $10$?  And also, in the last sentence of your first paragraph--in the edit--you say that "Since the last term is taken mod 10, the entire invariant is also taken mod 10".  How did you infer that the invariant was a constant mod $10$ from the $7^{th}$ term being mod $10$?  And everything else you explained is clear to me.  It is just these few points that still trouble me

Comment: @john fowles, Just a guess, really. Like I said, I'm not confident I could have found how to get the answer if i didn't know the answer.

Comment: So I figured out that $$\bigg((a+b) \text{ mod }c\bigg)\text{ mod c} = \bigg(a\text{ mod c} + b \text{ mod c}\bigg)\text{ mod c}$$ holds.  So based on your observation that we can write equivalences based on us knowing that the "same number of $x_i$'s are in the first $6$ as well as second $6$", we would need to distribute $(x_1+...+x_6)$ mod $10 =x_1$mod$10 +...+x_6$ mod $10$.  And the only way for the distributive property to hold is to take everything mod $10$.  So I'm thinking that our need to distribute like I did just now, is what instructs us to have our invariant be mod $10$

Comment: Suppose we began by looking for an invariant equation.  Then taking the equation mod $10$ doesn't change the invariant from being a constant, if it was invariant without it.  So that step seems to be a step that doesn't change the invariant constant, but it allows us to equate coefficients on corresponding $x_i$'s.  I'll accept your answer and if you agree with my points here then perhaps you can edit your answer when explaining why we take the invariant equation mod $10$, since that'll explain things to new readers; that is if what I've said is correct.  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @johnfowles Glad I could help. I'll add your sentences to the beginning of my answer for posterity.