# Modular Arithmetic and the Distributive Property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I know that we can't apply the distributive property when doing modular arithmetic, e.g $$(a+b) \text{ mod }  c \neq a\text{ mod c} + b \text{ mod c}$$

But does it hold that

$$\bigg((a+b) \text{ mod }c\bigg)\text{ mod c} = \bigg(a\text{ mod c} + b \text{ mod c}\bigg)\text{ mod c}$$

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: Yes, in fact $(a+b) \bmod c = ((a \bmod c) + (b \bmod c)) \bmod c$

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Awesome!  If you have time, could you check out a question I asked yesterday that Involves finding an invariant equation to a sequence where the first 6 terms are given and the following term is given as the sum mod $10$ of the previous 6 terms?  Here's the link  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830927/how-to-find-invariant-equation